# How do I teleport only players that stand on a certain block?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm trying to create a minigame, but I want to create something where if you stand on a certain block, you get teleported back to the beginning. I think that I can use `/tp @e[type=Players] ~~~ testforblock ~~~ ~~~ ~~~ gold_block` will that work?

Comment: If you already have a command, why don't you just try it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [execute command](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands#execute) with the detect option:

```
execute @a ~ ~ ~ detect ~ ~-1 ~ minecraft:gold_block -1 tp @s ~ ~10 ~
```